# How can I make creases and hole on the mesh with subdivision surface modifier?

Tags: subdivision-surface

[image]

I'm copying this for practice and I make this.

[image]

But I don't know how to make creases and holes with a subdivision modifier.
I tried but it's weird.
Can anyone give me some tips?

w/ displace modifier
[image]

Comment: Maybe try using a Remesh Modifier before the Subdivision Surface. Try all the options (especially Blocks and Voxel). Keep in mind you might have to adjust the Octree Depth and Voxel Size to get the best results. (Try 5 Octree and 0.03 Voxel to start )

Comment: I tried Remesh Modifier but still don't know how to make creases and holes...

Comment: You could sculpt them in

Comment: Actually, this would be great with a displace modifier before the subdivision modifier.

Comment: As you advised I added voronoi and musgrave displace modifier before the subdivision modifier. How does it look? I actually wanted to make it better but don't know what to do... Thank you anyway! That was so helpful! @Psyonic

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't know how to tag someone... Thank you for your advice! @ChristopherBennett

Comment: Getting there @조상호. Keep going! There are many tutorials for displacement on YouTube

Comment: Thanks! @Psyonic